# OnStart method error

Tags: c#, task, azure-web-roles

I was reading this post [WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException on Azure web role start with Task.Wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633495/waithandlecannotbeopenedexception-on-azure-web-role-start-with-task-wait)

I could not reproduce the error using Visual Studio 2013, Azure SDK 2.3 or 2.4 on Windows 8.1, when creating a clean Azure Cloud Service project.

Did anyone hit the problem from the link above as well, and can share more insights on this? In addition, is the exception simple from the 'Debug' output console?

Any information would be much appreciated!

Thanks