# WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException occured in System.dll

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am getting a warning when trying to run a project in debug mode.

In previous projects, when I have gotten a warning, Visual Studio typically points me to a specific line of code.

But in this case, I have no idea how to respond to this warning.

What steps should I take to debug/fix this warning?

[image]

Comment: Difficult to say without more information - possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633495/waithandlecannotbeopenedexception-on-azure-web-role-start-with-task-wait

Comment: You'll have to look at the Call Stack window to see how it got there.   Not that likely you'll see much that you recognize however.   When you ask the debugger to stop on *every* exception then you'll inevitably get more than you bargained for.  Press F5 to continue or untick the "Break when this exception type is thrown" checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you need to do than to go back into the Debug menu Exceptions option and uncheck the "Thrown" option.

See on the exception dialog that it is listed as a [first chance exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception).  A first chance exception is sent to notify the debugger.  The second change exception is send back to the application to handle.

All that is happening is that you have the option "Thrown" option enabled and Visual Studio is pointing you to the code where the throw occurred, which is inside of a system dll, which is not surprising at all.